# Upload file from HTML page to server using cURL

Tags: html, shell, curl, lua, embedded-linux

I'm trying to have a webpage where you can upload a zip file and then the server (embedded linux) will download and save it. My HTML page has something like:

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="upload.cgi">
 <input type=file name=upload>
 <input type=submit name=press value="OK">
</form>
```

That creates upload and submit buttons. What I'm having trouble with is the backend script. I have lua & shell at my disposal (please don't give me a php example). I thought cURL would be the best way to do this but I'm not sure. I'm guessing what I need `upload.cgi` is something like this then:

```
curl --form upload=@localfilename --form press=OK
```

Where I pass in `localfilename` which is the name of the file that is being uploaded?

My questions are:

1. Is this the best/fastest way to upload a (30MB) zip file using an HTML page given my resources?
2. If so is my example the proper way to do this
   and syntacticly accurate?

Answer (score 0):

according to http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html (`man 1 curl`), you have to:

```
curl --data-urlencode upload@localfilename --data-urlencode press=OK http://url/to/upload.cgi
```